# Openshot-qt, version 2.6.1 al ejecutarse se cierra de inmediato en Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, app

Instalé openshot-qt actualmente está la versión 2.6.1 después de actualizarse, en Ubuntu 20.04, no he logrado conseguir la solución googleando, tengo entendido que este error viene dando ya desde hace un tiempo atrás y en distintos distros de linux.

Al ejecutarlo se cierra de inmediato da el siguiente error en la consola.

```
openshot-qt
Loaded modules from: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app:             Mon Feb  7 19:45:56 2022            
INFO app:               Starting new session              
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app:           OpenShot (version 2.6.1-dev)          
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app: openshot-qt version: 2.6.1-dev
INFO app: libopenshot version: 0.2.7-dev
INFO app: platform: Linux-5.16.5-051605-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
INFO app: processor: x86_64
INFO app: machine: x86_64
INFO app: python version: 3.8.10
INFO app: qt5 version: 5.12.8
INFO app: pyqt5 version: 5.14.1
INFO project_data: Setting default profile to HD 1080i 30 fps
Screen VGA-1
   devicePixelRatio: 1.0
   logicalDotsPerInch: 96.0
   physicalDotsPerInch: 89.6470588235294
   availableSizes: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1400, 873)
INFO language: Qt Detected Languages: ['es-VE', 'es']
INFO language: LANG Environment Variable: es_VE.UTF-8
INFO language: LOCALE Environment Variable: 
INFO language: OpenShot Preference Language: Default
INFO app: Setting font to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/images/fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf
INFO logger_libopenshot: Connecting to libopenshot with debug port: 5556
INFO app: Setting custom dark theme
INFO ui_util: Initializing UI for MainWindow
INFO thumbnail: Starting thumbnail server listening on port 56049
INFO webengine: WebEngine backend initializing
INFO transition_model: updating transitions model.
INFO effects_model: updating effects model.
```

Desde aquí comienza el error relacionada con este archivo linux-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so.

He encontrado respuestas a errores parecidos pero no logro hallar la solución.

```
INFO version: Found current version: {'error_rate_unstable': 0.05, 'openshot_version': '2.6.1', 'error_rate_stable': 0.05}
INFO emoji_model: updating emoji model.
INFO main_window: InitCacheSettings
INFO main_window: cache-mode: CacheMemory
INFO main_window: cache-limit-mb: 250
INFO main_window: Creating CacheMemory object with 262144000 byte limit
INFO preview_thread: QThread Start Method Invoked
ERROR main_window: Unhandled crash detected: linux-/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_dri.so 0xb5a989 [0x7fdcc57cc989]
INFO main_window: updateStatusChanged
INFO main_window: recover_backup
INFO project_data: Setting default profile to HD 1080i 30 fps
INFO preview_thread: player Position(): 1
INFO video_widget: Load: Set video widget display aspect ratio to: 1.7777777910232544
INFO video_widget: Set video widget pixel aspect ratio to: 1.0
INFO main_window: updateStatusChanged
Sentry initialized with 0.05 error reporting rate (unstable)
INFO webengine: Registering WebChannel connection with WebEngine
INFO preview_thread: player Position(): 1
INFO timeline: Adjusting max size of preview image: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(660, 372)
INFO preview_thread: player Position(): 1
Property 'modal'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'windowModality'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'enabled'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'geometry'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'frameGeometry'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'normalGeometry'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'x'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'y'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'pos'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'frameSize'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'size'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'width'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'height'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'rect'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'childrenRect'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'childrenRegion'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'sizePolicy'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'minimumSize'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'maximumSize'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'minimumWidth'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'minimumHeight'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'maximumWidth'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'maximumHeight'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'sizeIncrement'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'baseSize'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'palette'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'font'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'cursor'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'mouseTracking'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'tabletTracking'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'isActiveWindow'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'focusPolicy'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'focus'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'contextMenuPolicy'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'updatesEnabled'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'visible'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'minimized'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'maximized'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'fullScreen'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'sizeHint'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'minimumSizeHint'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'acceptDrops'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'windowOpacity'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'windowModified'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'toolTip'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'toolTipDuration'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'statusTip'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'whatsThis'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'accessibleName'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'accessibleDescription'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'layoutDirection'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'autoFillBackground'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'styleSheet'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'locale'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'windowFilePath'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'inputMethodHints'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'title'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'url'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'selectedText'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'hasSelection'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
Property 'zoomFactor'' of object 'TimelineWebView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
INFO webview: Qt Ready
INFO webview: Angular Ready
```

alguien tiene idea de como solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Te ocurre abriendo la aplicación tal cual o al intentar abrir un archivo directamente?  Lo digo porque a mi me pasó con un archivo en concreto y tuve que editarlo a pelo y conseguí hacerlo funcionar eliminando un caracter corrupto del mismo que vi por casualidad, pues eran miles de lineas, je.

Comment: Buenas ocurre al abrir la aplicación

Comment: ya, pero recuerdas cual fue el ultimo archivo que abristes?  quizas esta intentandolo abrir.  Intenta abrir otro desde el nautilus directamente a ver si cuela

Comment: por otro lado, ahora que lo veo, el driver nouveau es de video y es el que usa por defecto cuando no instalas drivers de fabricante... ¿has mirado en `Software y actualizaciones`, dentro de la pestaña `controladores adicionales` si te sale alguno de tu fabricante de la tarjeta de video?  Quizas es un buen momento para probarlo

Comment: masterguru, no he podido abrir ningún archivo ya que me esta dando este error desde un principio, es decir desde que lo instale.

Comment: Comprueba lo que he dicho de los `controladores adicionales`a ver si tienes suerte y te aparecen más drivers de video que puedas instalar y quizas superar ese error relacionado con el driver de nouveau

Comment: ¿y si lo lanzas desde terminal contra un archivo creado cualquiera tambien te lo hace?

Comment: probare desde el terminar abrir un archivo no lo he hecho y te aviso

Comment: @masterguru lo hice e igualmente da el mismo erro y no se ejecuta, y si tengo una tarjeta gráfica nvidia 340 no se si por ella me da el error

Comment: Ejem, a ver, si tienes una tarjeta nvidia tienen que aparecerte drivers para nvidia en los `controladores adicionales` dentro de `Software y actualizaciones` y debes poder elegir uno de los que aparezcan.  Esos teoricamente son mejores que los nouveau que estas usando ahora, pues son del fabricante directo.

Comment: O si no lo encuentras, escribe `ubuntu-drivers devices` en un terminal a ver que opciones posibles te aparecen

Comment: si me apareció el controlador privativo de la nvidea, al mandar a que se configurara dio un error también, y por lo general este controlador en Linux me ha dado problemas casi siempre

Comment: escribe en el terminal `uname -a` y pegame lo que pone

Comment: Linux marlon-H61MHV2 5.16.8-051608-generic #202202101327-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 10 13:36:40 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Pues quizás ahi tienes el problema de los drivers de Nvidia, pues segun parece quieren ejecutarse en un kernel 5.4 en lugar del tuyo que está mucho más adelante. El mio es el 5.4 y estoy al dia de updates y upgrades, por lo tanto entiendo que has forzado esa actualizacion de algun modo. Si miras en la primera respuesta de [este post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365631/nvidia-340-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04) te explican en 4 pasos como cambiar el kernel e instalar los drivers

Comment: ok @masterguru gracias por toda la ayuda revisare el post